# How to get lighting text effect

Tags: lighting, portrait

I recently follow this account and really love how the text is projected on the model.

I tried doing it with a projector however the projector also projects black light and it does not give the same effect at all.

Link to image:
https://www.instagram.com/p/CRQM7nusDmi/

Image:

[image: red text over model]

[image: writing cheek]

How could I achieve that kind of effect?

PS: If someone also knows how to get this kind of red backlighting that would be awesome.

https://www.instagram.com/p/CIu625rMvS5/

Comment: "projects black light"? Please define 'black light'.

Comment: Are you sure the text effect is not just photoshopped and actually achieved through some kind of projector ?

Comment: @Tetsujin if I use a projector you can see the text and you can see light projected on the rest of the face of the model when I tried it. In the first picture you can see there is no other projection it looks like only the text is projected. Maybe through a laser?

Comment: Maybe they just used a *better* projector.

Comment: @silverrahul how would you get such realistic reflection as well as lighting around the nose.

Comment: @Tetsujin a projector by definition projects light good or bad there will still be light projected to the subject no?

Comment: @Mederic How to get such lighting and reflection around nose through photoshop is a  different question and it is a good question . My point is that this could very well be a photoshopped effect. Maybe you should include that in the question as well . Like "How could i achieve this effect whether through camera / lighting or through photoshop ?" Unless you already meant that. I just got the impression that you feel, this text effect was definitely done without photoshop . I am not sure that assumption has a good basis

Comment: @Mederic There are plenty of tutorials etc. on how to create text projection on to face effect in photoshop . This is just one of them https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7iS-gOJs0HQ    .   Maybe this might be helpful to you

Comment: A **good** projector projects light where there should be image & not where there shouldn't. i see no need to do something like this by any other method.

Comment: It looks to me like they are using **Laser Text Projectors**. This would also produce what you called *red backlighting* if used in a room filled with smoke or haze. Note that using this around eyes can be dangerous.